# Compiling C code using multiple compilers

Tags: c, windows, compilation

I have just recently decided to learn C. I notice there is multiple compilers I can download. If I write C code for one compiler, it should work for all of the compilers, correct?

Comment: It is an excellent idea to compile your code with as many different compilers as reasonably possible (N > 1 is much better than N == 1).  You will get different views on the issues with the code.  Make sure you also turn the warning level on the compilers to a high level, and then heed what they say.  For example, if one of the compilers is GCC, you might use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to spot the majority of problems.  You'd also specify a standard, such as `-std=c11`, and maybe add `-pedantic` to avoid using compiler extensions by accident. I use more options than that with GCC.

Comment: It can be a tad painful keeping multiple compilers up to date with lots of libraries (your own and third party) built for each etc. It's worth looking at tools like `cmake`, which can build via multiple compilers. That's not a magic everything-done-for-you solution, but it can help. I used to switch back-and-forth between MinGW GCC and VC++ a lot a few years back. I still use cmake even just using GCC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes

Long answer:

Yes, but only if (and not limited to):

- Your code doesn't use compiler specific stuff that's not available on the other compiler
- The libraries your code relies on are available and set up correctly on the other compiler
- Your code doesn't invoke/rely on undefined or implementation-defined behavior
- The other compiler compiles roughly with the same C standard your current compiler.

I'll add more to the list as I think of them.

Comment: By undefined behavior you mean one compiler could handle undefined behavior better than another compiler? Meaning errors in one compiler but not the other, correct?

Comment: @user3155415 Undefined behavior is exactly what it says: undefined. This means that two different compilers can do two completely different things. Neither is "better" than the other. Undefined behavior is always an error in logic.

Comment: Implementation-defined behaviour need not be a huge problem.  For example, the value of `LONG_MAX` is implementation defined, so if your code changes what it does based on the value of `LONG_MAX`, it is showing implementation-defined behaviour.  But that may not be a problem at all.  Undefined behaviour is the problematic one, and ['nasal demons'](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) — as in, 'undefined behaviour may bring demons flying out of your nose' — should be memorable (if implausible).

Comment: On undefined behavior - if you have old-style data structure code with lots of pointer casts, it's very easy for that to have undefined behavior. Specifically, the compiler may not spot that two pointers are actually the same pointer. This pointer alias issue can lead to references via one pointer failing to see changes written via the other. It's actually newer and better compilers that tend to get the bugs - more sophisticated optimization tends to find bugs. In this case, alias pointers aren't a (visible) bug if every read/write is forced to main memory - it's just slow.

Answer (score 2):

In the C standard there are two types of ['compiler-dependent'](http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html) issues defined:

- **Implementation-defined behavior**: The behavior may vary from compiler to compiler, but the compiler must provide some sort of consistent behavior, and must document this behavior.

  An example, straight from the standard: "An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right.". In other words, the result of **-1 >> 1** may vary between compilers, but the compiler has to be consistent about it.
- **Undefined behavior**: The moment you hit undefined behavior, anything - and I do mean anything can happen.

You also need to watch out for constraint violations. Often the standard specifies things like "[main] shall be defined with a return type of int [...]" (§5.1.2.2.1/1). This is equivalent to, "If main is declared with a return type other than int, the program's behavior is undefined." (see §4.2, where the standard explicitly endorses this interpretation)

Note that some implementation-defined behavior has limits - eg, the value of sizeof(int) is implementation defined, but you know that **sizeof(int) >= sizeof(short) && sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)** - so just having any implementation-defined behavior doesn't mean you can't say anything about what the program does.